# Can't do different set operation value python

Tags: python, set

This set of value :

```
x = {'5005814,Male,1.63,66.2',
'5005814,Male,1.52,57.3',
'5005833,Female,1.65,62.4'}
```

Can't make this output from set operation

```
print(x-{"Male"})
expect output --> '5005814,Male,1.63,66.2', '5005814,Male,1.52,57.3'
```

Comment: `x` doesn't contain `"Male"` though; it contains strings that contain `"Male"`. You'll need to iterate the strings in the set and do `in` checks or something similar, because what you're trying to do is beyond set operations (searching through strings). Also, in your example, that should be `x - {"Female")` shouldn't it?

Comment: yes, it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'5005814,Male,1.63,66.2'` is a string and does not have any relation to `Male`.
You don't need to do that like that. You can use `in` to check if `male` existed in that string

```py
{i for i in x if 'Male' in i}
```

output

```
{'5005814,Male,1.52,57.3', '5005814,Male,1.63,66.2'}
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I want to use set operation as x-{"Male"} how to do this point.

Comment: @user11029107 You can't use a set operation for this. It's the wrong tool for the job. To make it work, you would need to split your data on commas or something so that `"Male"` itself is a string in the set. That would drastically change your data though.

Comment: See `hash('Male')` and `hash('5005814,Male,1.52,57.3')` is totally different. So no way you can compare the both

Comment: And hash is something with a slight change in input-output change drastically, so it's not like having `male` in both there will be a similarity.

Comment: While this works for OP's case (+1) it is fragile in the sense that it would fail if `Male` and `Female` were lower case. But -- that is more OP's problem if they want to generalize the code.

Comment: That is a great catch sir!